# Do indecomposable abelian groups of inacessible cardinal rank exist?

Tags: set-theory, abelian-groups, large-cardinals

In Fuchs' *Infinite Abelian Groups*, it is proved that  there exist indecomposable torsion-free abelian groups of every rank smaller than the first strongly inaccessible cardinal. It is natural to ask: is it known for which ranks $\geq$ first strongly inaccessible cardinal there exist such groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Theorem 2.1 of the following paper, there are indecomposable torsion-free abelian groups of any infinite cardinality.

*Shelah, Saharon*, [**Infinite Abelian groups, Whitehead problem and some constructions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02757281), Isr. J. Math. 18, 243-256 (1974). [ZBL0318.02053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0318.02053). On Shelah's website at https://shelah.logic.at/files/95858/44.pdf